# Program not drawing graphics

Tags: c#

I've been following the instructions for an assignment and I can't see any issues with the code (no error messages and the program runs without crashing), but the program does not draw the graphics. It's supposed to random out 200 random numbers between 1-100, and then sort them into a graph with a bubble sort

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] number = new int[200];
        Random generator = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                number[i] = generator.Next(1, 101);
            }
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BubbleSort(number);
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Assigns origo
            Point origo = new Point(40,150);

            //Draw x and y axes
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, origo.X, origo.Y, origo.X, origo.Y - 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, origo.X, origo.Y, origo.X + 200, origo.Y);

            //Draw all points
            for(int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, origo.X + i, origo.Y - number[i], 2, 2);
            }
        }

        public void BubbleSort(int[] list)
        {
            for (int m = list.Length - 1; m > 0; m--)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < m; n++)
                {
                    if (list[n] > list[n + 1])
                    {
                        int temp = list[n];
                        list[n] = list[n + 1];
                        list[n + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program should draw 200 points when you press the button "Generate" and then sort them into a line/graph when you press "Sort", but the program isn't drawing anything when I press the buttons.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the `Paint` event? Is that code every called?

Comment: I suggest debugging the whole process and see what gets called and what not.

Comment: Use "override OnPaint" instead of Form_Paint

Comment: Please check whether `Form1_Paint()` is attached to `Form1.Paint` event or not first. There should be `this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);` statement in `Form1.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: This question lacks basic debugging, please learn how to use the debugger, and check everything is working and the values of the drawing points

Comment: In VS, place your cursor on a (non-blank) line inside Form1_Paint method. Hit F9 (A red dot will appear next to the line. This is a breakpoint.). Run in Debug mode. Is the execution ever halted and VS highlights that line? (i.e. Breakpoint gets hit)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and the help! The program worked properly when I changed `private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)` to `protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)`